# How to find an arXiv endorser

Tags: publications, arxiv

I have recently completed a manuscript and I want it to submit to the arXiv. But there I find that there is an endorsement requirement. But since I am quite new in this field (and this is my first time wanting to submit to arXiv), I don't know how to find an endorser myself. I have mailed the *admin* also but in reply they also told me that *searching for an endorser is a responsibility of the author himself*. So, can anyone help me regarding the process as to how to find an endorser?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you go to a paper on the arXiv (for example, this one of mine: http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7357), at the bottom, there is a link that reads "Which authors of this paper are endorsers?"  If you click through, you'll see something like

> Ben Webster: Is registered as an author of this paper.
> Can endorse for math.AG, math.AT, math.CO, math.CT, math.GR, math.GT, math.QA, math.RA, math.RT, math.SG.

which means I can endorse submitters in algebraic geometry, algebraic topology, combinatorics, category theory, group theory, geometric topology, quantum algebra, rings & algebras, representation theory and symplectic geometry.

Presumably you know of some papers on the arXiv related to yours, so look at their authors.  If you don't know of any, then maybe you should rethink whether the site is a good fit for you.

**EDIT:** I wanted to comment: I've now received several emails now based on this post asking for endorsement (maybe 1 a year or so), but *never* for fields I can actually endorse in.  So, please, pay attention to that detail if you are going to send someone an email and ask for endorsement. Try looking at papers which are in the correct subject area.

Comment: Feel free not to answer this if you don't want to, but...have you in fact ever endorsed someone on the arxiv?  (I haven't.)

Comment: Once, as a graduate student, I endorsed a fellow student.  Not since.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, I did endorse someone for an arXiv submission once. Meanwhile, I got an email a few days ago requesting an endorsement, evidently one paper on Goldbach, one on Pollock conjectures. I have not replied. This guy is polite, but I don't see how I am involved; I have not answered or requested the papers, which are not in my area.

Answer (score 9):

The following order of steps seems reasonable to me:

1. Do you personally know any other researchers in the endorsement domain? Consider in particular former colleagues, former advisors, anybody with whom you communicated about your research.

   1. Check whether any of these people already can endorse. To do so find an ArXiv publication by them and check the *Which authors of this paper are endorsers?* link at the bottom of the page.
   2. Check whether any of these people may become an endorser by claiming ownership of their publications. If somebody co-authored Arxiv publications in the endorsement domain in the last five years, all they may need to do is claim ownership (which is comparably easy) to be able to endorse. Note that the number of required publications depends on the domain. (More details [here](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement))
   3. Check whether any of these people may become endorsers by publishing one or more existing peer-reviewed publication on the Arxiv. Again the publications must not be older than five years and they must be published in a journal whose copyright agreement allows this. Be aware that preparing papers for Arxiv publication might involve some time and work. Therefore this would be asking for more of a favour than just endorsement. On the other hand people who personally know you do not have to read your paper, so you might still cause less work than asking somebody else for endorsement.
2. Is there anybody with endorsement capabilities (see above) in the direct vicinity of your topic, i.e., somebody who might be particularly interested to read your work and can easily read it? Consider people whose work you cited or whom you would suggest as reviewers for your paper when submitting to a journal.
3. Finally, consider other people who can endorse in the respective domain. The closer they are to your subject, the better. Also you are probably more successful with lower-ranking academics as they are less flooded with requests and have more time on their hands.

In all cases, heed [the Arxiv’s guideline not to “email large numbers of potential endorsers at once”](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a registered student in a recognized university or institute, you can register in arXiv with your school email address, then you do not need endorsement. After submission, the moderator takes charge and decides if acknowledging your paper to publish.

Comment: From [arXiv Endorsement](https://info.arxiv.org/help/endorsement.html) : "_In most cases, automatic endorsement is given to authors from known academic institutions and research facilities. arXiv submitters are therefore encouraged to associate an institutional email address, if they have one, with their arXiv account (see author registration help). This will expedite the endorsement process._". Please note that they state "**In most cases**"

Comment: Would that be ... *registered student or researcher in a 'recognised' university or institute* ... *then you **may** not need endorsement*