# Need an endorser for arxive in computer science society

Tags: arxiv

Recently,  I have published a paper in one of the renowned journals. The journal policy allows me to submit it to arxiv provided that the copyright notice is included in the text. However, since it is my first time to upload in arxiv I need an endorser in the computer science society. I was wondering if anyone in this forum can be of help.

Comment: Someone who cites your paper in the renowned journal may be happy to help.

Comment: You could of course also actually read what is written on arXiv about getting an endorser. This post is pretty much not what they say to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find an arXiv endorser](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20186/how-to-find-an-arxiv-endorser)

Answer (score 2):

Someone who cites your paper in the renowned journal may be happy to help.

The renowned journal editor may be happy to do it.

Co-authors of the paper likely would do this.

Others in your department or college may be willing to do this.

Post a preprint on research gate or similar. Ask for a review from an arXiv member.