# How to ensure my papers are indexed by Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar, indexing

I have some papers published in some journals in India, but Google Scholar does not index those journals. What approach can I take to get these papers indexed by Google Scholar?

I tried uploading the papers to Academia.edu, but it didn't work. I don't have an institutional email and webpage at this moment. My research field is computer science.

Comment: google scholar indexes arxiv.org

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your comment. Any other option?

Comment: @Thomas The problem with arxiv.org is that when I want to submit my paper, it says "You are not endorsed for this archive. See endorsement help or request endorsement". And I don't know someone who can endorse me.

Comment: Please read the question [How to find an arXiv endorser](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20186/546)

Comment: @scaaahu So, there is no option other than arxiv?

Comment: You could try [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org) or your local institutional repository. There are also some discipline specific repositories. Please add your research field to the question.

Comment: Edited--This is receiving close votes as a "shopping" question, but it seemed to me like that could be solved by slightly rewording it.  The answer, to me proves that it is not essentially just a shopping question, since it gave some approaches to finding a repository rather than a list of repositories.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the already mentioned options [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) and [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org), you can also check if your have a local institutional repository and whether it is indexed by Google Scholar. Additionally, you can search in [OpenDOAR](http://www.opendoar.org/find.php) (DOAR = Directory of Open Access Repositories) for repositories based upon subject area, content type, repository type, ...