# Looking for an endorser to publish on arxiv.org as well as other suggestions

Tags: publications, physics

My grandfather, a long since retired professor, recently finished a very long in the making paper, which tries to cover a lot of ground around physics and general nature science. He is very old-school, so he asked me to see if I can get his paper seen by people familiar with the field. I tried to publish on arxiv.org, but I need an endorser.

The author is 90 years old and has been out of academic circulation for over 30 years, long before arxiv and the internet.

I am posting a link to the paper here (29 pages), nothing huge, and I'm asking for anyone interested to comment as well as for advice on how to get endorsement, and about other locations I can post it at besides arxiv.org

https://app.box.com/s/2m4z6cfyaoje9zc3j3i0mx5sibfi5eaj

Thank you

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20186/how-to-find-an-arxiv-endorser

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please note that this site is not a good place to solicit endorsements (you can ask about how to get one though). Also note that your grandfather may still have a university e-mail address which may help him bypass the endorsement step.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist  This isn't a solicitation for endorsement, it's a genuine set of questions. You have to understand, the author is a very old man, who left the academia before emails, and neither the institution he worked at nor the country where it was located exists any longer (the USSR is gone). All he wants is for this work to get some views from people who actually are able to understand what he is talking about. 

I know academic paper publishing is serious business, but we are simply trying to indulge a nice old man who invested years into this research without any outside help.