# Endorsement for arXiv when shifting field of research

Tags: preprint

I have worked for many years in data analysis in molecular biology / medicine / medical physics and also worked in such research institutions publishing a large number of papers. Therefore I have frequently uploaded preprints on e.g. https://www.medrxiv.org and https://www.biorxiv.org/.

Now I have for the frist time written a paper that does not involve medicine or biology in any aspect and realised that https://arxiv.org/ is not letting me upload a preprint as an "endorsement" is needed (the  paper is already submitted to a journal and in review). Interestingly no one I have worked with over the last 10 years has ever uploaded to https://arxiv.org/ (because the all work on biology/medicine data) and therefore no one can endorse me.

Where can I get an endorsement from? I have uploaded the preprint now on SSRN but would like to avoid that in future as it belongs to Elsevier.

[How to find an arXiv endorser](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20186/how-to-find-an-arxiv-endorser) does not answer this question as it is not only outdated (9 years) but also the answer itself "If you don't know of any, then maybe you should rethink whether the site is a good fit for you." is not applicable here and in general unnecessary.

Comment: An endorser does not have to be your collaborator: Do you  know anybody who might be willing and is able to endorse your paper?  If so, just ask them.

Comment: The arXiv endorsement system is a feature, not a bug; what you are encountering is by design, even if it's frustrating / counterproductive in your case. In any case: while the answers on the linked question may be old, but they don't seem to be outdated; a new question posted today would likely produce the same answers.